# D3 v4: linear scales for bar chart using JSON data from XML Http Request

Tags: javascript, d3.js, xmlhttprequest

I am struggling to create a bar chart using D3 v4 to draw a bar chart using data pulled from a XML HTTP Request. This is for the first challenge in FreeCodeCamp's D3 certification track: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/data-visualization/data-visualization-projects/visualize-data-with-a-bar-chart

I managed to pull the data as a JSON object and I can iterate through it using D3. The JSON object looks like this:

```
 {
  "errors": {},
  "id": 120140,
  "source_name": "Federal Reserve Economic Data",
  "source_code": "FRED",
  "code": "GDP",
  "name": "Gross Domestic Product, 1 Decimal",
  "urlize_name": "Gross-Domestic-Product-1-Decimal",
  "display_url": "http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/GDP.txt",
  "description": "Units: Billions of Dollars\nSeasonal Adjustment: Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate\nNotes: A Guide to the National Income and Product Accounts of the United States (NIPA) - (http://www.bea.gov/national/pdf/nipaguid.pdf)",
  "updated_at": "2015-12-14T20:00:28.561Z",
  "frequency": "quarterly",
  "from_date": "1947-01-01",
  "to_date": "2015-07-01",
  "column_names": [
    "DATE",
    "VALUE"
  ],
  "private": false,
  "type": null,
  "premium": false,
  "data": [
    [
      "1947-01-01",
      243.1
    ],
    [
      "1947-04-01",
      246.3
    ],
    [
      "1947-07-01",
      250.1
    ],
    [
      "1947-10-01",
      260.3
    ],...}
```

The `"data": [],` is the element I am trying to visualise.

I managed to draw 's using the integers in the array ([
      "1947-01-01",
      243.1
    ]) but where I am struggling is in applying scales so the chart is drawn within the  generated. I tried using `d3.scalelinear()` for the x and y axis:

```
//setting the scales for the chart
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(chart_data, (d) => d[0])])
                    .range([margin, width - margin]);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(chart_data, (d) => d[1])])
                        .range([height - margin, margin]);
```

But when I try to apply the xScale to the 'x' attribute of the chart or the yScale to te 'height' attribute I get a NaN error. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have uploaded my code to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/siyafrica/r2wmxtpj/2/

Comment: does `d[0]` look like a number? No. Its a **date**. So xScale should be something like a time-scale. And setting xScale domain to `[0,max(d[0])]` and then calling `xScale(d[1])` most likely will result in an out of domain value.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try out your solution.